# Is it possible to set a users memberOf property in Active Directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I need to create a Powershell script that sets some user attributes in Active Directory.

I'm using the Set-AdUser command and passing in a user object as follows:

```
$user = Get-AdUser -Identity $userIdentity
$user.MemberOf = $dn_of_group
Set-ADUser -Instance $user
```

this returns an error of 'The adapter cannot set the value of property "MemberOf"'.

Is it possible to set the MemberOf property from powershell?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify the `MemberOf` property - you need to [add the user to the group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx) using the `Add-ADGroupMember` Cmdlet:

```
Add-ADGroupMember $dn_of_group $user
```