# Add group membership to AD with PyAD

Tags: python, dns, pyad

I've been trying to add group membership to my user in AD via PyAD.

```
from pyad import *
pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="someSchool.local", username="someAdmin", password='somePassword')

user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.from_cn('Student999')
print(user.get_attribute('memberOf'))
user.update_attribute('mail','student999@someschool.com')
user.append_to_attribute('memberOf','CN=Active,OU=Groups,OU=Students,DC=someSchool,DC=local')
```

Everything works except **append_to_attribute** method.
Print method correctly prints members' list added to user account.
Method **update_attribute** correctly updates mail field.
But when I run **append_to_attribute** and I try to add next member group to my user, it throws an exception:

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occured.', (0, 'Active Directory', 'Server is unwilling to process the request\r\n', None, 0, -2147016651), None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.
According to this [Is it possible to set a users memberOf property in Active Directory using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447609/is-it-possible-to-set-a-users-memberof-property-in-active-directory-using-powers) attribute memberOf cannot be updated.

So, this works for me:

```
from pyad import *
pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="someSchool.local", username="someAdmin", password='somePassword')

user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.from_cn('Student999')
group = pyad.adgroup.ADGroup.from_dn("CN=Active,OU=Groups,OU=Students,DC=someSchool,DC=local")  
user.add_to_group(group)
```